# Is it necessary to put async in bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I am trying to add bluebird promises in the project. I am using NodeJS, Express, Mongodb. This is my sample model file

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Blue Bird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')
const schema = mongoose.SchemaAsync

const acModel = new schema({
    // Schema here
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.modelAsync('myModel', acModel)
```

But is it necessary to put Async everywhere? For example `SchemaAsync, modelAsync`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add Async at every call.

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

User.findOne({}).then(function(user){

});
```

I guess you need to add `async` when you do this

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you use async await you end up using the standard Promise object instead of bluebird